# Good Dynamics Phonegap SDK - simulation mode hangs on "retrieving policies"

Tags: cordova, good-dynamics

I am attempting to get a simple "Hello World" app running, using Cordova and the Good PhoneGap SDK. I can create, build and run a simple cordova app in both the Android and iOS simulators (from an ios machine). Once I add the Good SDK (using the gdEnableApp.sh or the gdCreateApp.sh scripts) and set the GDLibraryMode to GDEnterpriseSimulation, the app runs in the emulator and opens to the Good "access key" page (so far so good).  But after entering any email address and access key, the next page appears and begins stepping through the Good process - but once it reaches the "Retrieving Policies" step, it hangs there. This happens consistently, regardless of the emulator I am using, and happens for both Android and iOS.

My understanding is that the Good SDK cannot route through a proxy server, so my development is now on a stand-alone machine connect directly to an open network - not behind a corporate firewall.

Has anyone used the Good PhoneGap plug-in?  I am thinking this simply does not work in emulation mode.  Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in their latest SDK  release in GDEnterpriseSimulation mode. However it should work fine with GDEnterprise mode as when you deploy it real life scenario.

You can able to run in GDEnterpriseSimulation mode also with their previous releases. It will work fine. I checked and able to see the password change page that is the page you get after entering email and access key.

Also make sure you are capable of pinging these url's

```
• gdentgw.good.com 
• gdrelay.good.com 
• gdweb.good.com 
• gdmdc.good.com
```